# Como fazer um pop up aparecer apos apertar um botao usando JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Eu fiz um formulario com o JQuery accordion e ao final um botao de enviar. Apos apertar o botao deveria aparecer uma mensagem pop up, mas esta dando erro. 
Meu pop up aparece quando a pagina se inicia e esse botao esta meio que inutil porque o pop up deveria vir depois.
Alquem pode me ajudar?

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script> <!---  jQuery UI “Submit” button --->
        $( function() {
            $( ".widget input[type=submit], .widget a, .widget button" ).button();
            $( "button, input, a" ).click( function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!---  jQuery UI Dialog message --->
    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
        });
    </script>


            <div class="widget">
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
            <div id="dialog" title="Order Complete">
                    <p>Your order has been placed.</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco confusa. Podia tentar detalhar melhor e adicionar um exemplo visível (usando o [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) por exemplo do problema?

Comment: Creio que `button()` não seja um método. Mas gostaria de ver toda esta parte do código para deixar uma resposta mais aprimorada à pergunta.

Comment: ok vou tentar colocar o codigo de uma forma mais clara

Comment: Mas o que eu preciso eh:
- criar um botao usando o Jquery;
- criar uma caixa de dialogo(pop up) usando o JQuery;
- e por final fazer o pop up aparecer somente quando eu clicar nesse botao

Comment: Eu obtive essas funcoes por esse site: https://jqueryui.com/button/

Comment: eu nao sei o pq o site nao me permite colocar a parte body na pergunta de uma forma limpa. Neste caso as divs sao da parte body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao usar `$( function() {`, você está executando a instrução no momento do ready da página e não quando o botão é clicado.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

Segue a função para o seu problema:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog();
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">


<div>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display:none;">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: conferi aqui e ocorreu um erro que eu me deparei anteriormente. acontece que fazendo dessa forma que vc me falou, nao importa aonde eu clique na minha pagina o pop up esta aparecendo, mesmo se eu clicar no menu index o pop up aparece

Comment: @WagnerGualberto Nop, apenas será exibido o popup quando voce clicar sobre um elemento com o id submit.

Comment: Eu concordo, mas nao tenho nenhum outro id submit na minha pagina, ja chequei e isso que nao esta entrando na minha cabeca

Comment: @WagnerGualberto Wagner, é um código de exemplo, você pode adaptar ele para a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você não chama a função para mostrar seu popup na ação do botão. Tente algo como:

```
<script> <!---  jQuery UI “Submit” button --->
        $( function() {
            $( ".widget input[type=submit], .widget a, .widget button" ).button();
            $("#submit" ).click( function( event ) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Sim isso funcionou, mas como eu faco para evitar o pop up aparecer quando eu carregar a pagina?
autoOpen: false;?

Comment: Basta remover a segunda parte do código que começa depois do `<!---  jQuery UI Dialog message --->`

Comment: sim tanto tirando como colocando o autoOpen funcionou. obrigado, mas ainda tem um pequeno detalhe que esta incomodando meus olhos. Antes de eu cilcar no botao em baixo dele o testo "Your order has been placed." fica amostra. tem como tirar isso e soh mostrar quando o pop up aparecer?

Comment: leonardo... conferi aqui e ocorreu um erro que eu me deparei anteriormente. acontece que fazendo dessa forma que vc me falou, nao importa aonde eu clique na minha pagina o pop up esta aparecendo, mesmo se eu clicar no menu index o pop up aparece

Comment: Editado a minha resposta. Tente novamente, por favor.